# ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` when using custom callback to plot conv layer feature maps

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, tf.keras, asynccallback

I'm trying to implement a custom callback to get the feature maps of each `Conv2D` layer in the network plotted in `TensorBoard`.

When I run the code in `Example 1` I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-44-b691dabedd05> in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
     28 
     29         # 3) Build partial model
---> 30         partial_model = keras.Model(
     31             inputs=self.model.model.input,
     32             outputs=output_layers

ValueError: Output tensors of a Functional model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <keras.engine.base_layer.Layer object at 0x000002773C631CA0>
```

which seams as if it can't build the partial network, which is strange, because it succeeds when running is separately from the main thread.
Here is an example that illustrates the issue:

**Example 1**

```
import os
import io
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


'''
You can adjust the verbosity of the logs which are being printed by TensorFlow
by changing the value of TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL:
    0 = all messages are logged (default behavior)
    1 = INFO messages are not printed
    2 = INFO and WARNING messages are not printed
    3 = INFO, WARNING, and ERROR messages are not printed
'''
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

DEBUG = False


class ConvModel(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_image_shape = input_shape
        self.model = keras.Sequential([
            layers.Input(shape=input_shape),
            layers.Conv2D(32, 3),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.MaxPool2D(),
            layers.Conv2D(64, 5),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.MaxPool2D(),
            layers.Conv2D(128, 3, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.Flatten(),
            layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)),
            layers.Dropout(0.5),
            layers.Dense(10)
        ])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.model(inputs)


def find_sub_string(string: str, sub_string: str):
    return True if string.find(sub_string) > -1 else False


def get_file_type(file_name: str):
    file_type = None
    if isinstance(file_name, str):
        dot_idx = file_name.find('.')
        if dot_idx > -1:
            file_type = file_name[dot_idx + 1:]
    return file_type


def get_image_from_figure(figure):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    plt.savefig(buffer, format='png')

    plt.close(figure)
    buffer.seek(0)

    image = tf.image.decode_png(buffer.getvalue(), channels=4)
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
    return image


class ConvLayerVis(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, X, figure_configs: dict, log_dir: str, log_interval: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.X_test = X

        n_dims = len(self.X_test.shape)
        assert 2 < n_dims < 5, f'The shape of the test image should be less than 5 and grater than 2, but current shape is {self.X_test.shape}'

        # In case the image is not represented as a tensor - add a dimension to the left for the batch
        if len(self.X_test.shape) < 4:
            self.X_test = np.reshape(self.X_test, (1,) + self.X_test.shape)

        self.file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)
        self.figure_configs = figure_configs
        self.log_interval = log_interval

    def on_training_begin(self, logs=None):
        pass

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # 1) Get the layers
        if epoch % self.log_interval == 0:
            # 1) Get the layers
            output_layer_tuples = [(idx, layer) for idx, layer in enumerate(self.model.model.layers) if find_sub_string(layer.name, 'conv2d') or find_sub_string(layer.name, 'max_pooling2d')]
            output_layers = [layer_tuple[1] for layer_tuple in output_layer_tuples]

            # 2) Get the layer names
            conv_layer_name_tuples = [(layer_tuple[0], f'Layer #{layer_tuple[0]} - Conv 2D ') for layer_tuple in output_layer_tuples if find_sub_string(layer_tuple[1].name, 'conv2d')]
            max_pool_layer_name_tuples = [(layer_tuple[0], f'Layer #{layer_tuple[0]} - Max Pooling 2D') for layer_tuple in output_layer_tuples if find_sub_string(layer_tuple[1].name, 'max_pooling2d')]

            layer_name_tuples = (conv_layer_name_tuples + max_pool_layer_name_tuples)
            layer_name_tuples.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

            layer_names = [layer_name_tuple[1] for layer_name_tuple in layer_name_tuples]

            # 3) Build partial model
            partial_model = keras.Model(
                inputs=model.model.input,
                outputs=output_layers
            )

            # 4) Get the feature maps
            feature_maps = partial_model.predict(self.X_test)

            # 5) Plot
            rows, cols = self.figure_configs.get('rows'), self.figure_configs.get('cols')
            for feature_map, layer_name in zip(feature_maps, layer_names):
                fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=self.figure_configs.get('figsize'))
                for row in range(rows):
                    for col in range(cols):
                        ax[row][col].imshow(feature_map[0, :, :, row+col], cmap=self.figure_configs.get('cmap'))
                fig.suptitle(f'{layer_name}')

                with self.file_writer.as_default():
                    tf.summary.image(f'{layer_name} Feature Maps', get_image_from_figure(figure=fig), step=epoch)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

    # Load the data
    (X, y), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
    X, X_test = X.astype(np.float32) / 255.0, X_test.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    n, w, h, c = X.shape[0], X.shape[1], X.shape[2], X.shape[3]
    n_test, w_test, h_test, c_test = X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], X_test.shape[2], X_test.shape[3]

    print(f'''
Dataset Stats:
    Number of train images: {n}
    Dimensions: 
        > Train: 
            width = {w}, height = {h}, channels = {c}
        > Test: 
            width = {w_test}, height = {h_test}, channels = {c_test}
    ''')

    # Model with keras.Sequential
    model = ConvModel(input_shape=(w, h, c))
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-4), metrics=['accuracy'])

    log_dir = f'./logs/{dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}'

    callbacks = [
        keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
            log_dir=log_dir,
            write_images=True
        ),
        ConvLayerVis(
            X=X[0],
            figure_configs=dict(rows=5, cols=5, figsize=(35, 35), cmap='gray'),
            log_dir=f'{log_dir}/train',
            log_interval=3
        )
    ]
    model.fit(
        X,
        y,
        batch_size=64,
        epochs=15,
        callbacks=callbacks
    )
```

Thanks in advance for any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the problem:

```
output_layers = [layer_tuple[1].output for layer_tuple in output_layer_tuples]
```

Should have recovered the `output` attribute of each layer.